# Symfony API The controller must return a response

Tags: php, api, symfony

I created a little crud system with a OneToMany relationship and want to create a little api as well.

I generated a new ApiBundle and added 1 controller for 1 of my entities that looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace ApiBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
use DataBundle\Entity\Job;

class JobController extends FOSRestController
{
    public function getAction()
    {
        $result = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DataBundle:Job')->findAll();

        if ($result === null) {
            return new View("There are no jobs in the database", Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function idAction($id)
    {
        $result = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DataBundle:Job')->find($id);

        if($result === null) {
            return new View("Job not found", Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }

        return $result;
    }

}
```

But when I make a call to /api/jobs i get the following error:

> Uncaught PHP Exception LogicException: "The controller must return a
>   response (Array(0 => Object(DataBundle\Entity\Job), 1 =>
>   Object(DataBundle\Entity\Job)) given)."

Anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Any help is appreciated!

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html

Answer (score 7):

The error is telling you to return a response. Something like this:

```
return new Response(
        'There are no jobs in the database', 
         Response::HTTP_OK
    );
```

or if you want a json response you can do something like this

```
return new JsonResponse(
         [
             'message' => 'There are no jobs in the database', 
         ]
         Response::HTTP_OK
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller must return an Response object, you are returning the $result.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this:

```
$view = $this->view($result, Response::HTTP_OK);
return $view;
```

Let us know if that works.